# Select list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables in a database, and one class in C# (`Letter`).

Tables: tblUser(Id, Name), tblLetter(Id, UserId, Title)

Letter: (Id, Title, UserName)

I want select data with linq, and use this code:

```
List<Letter> lst = new List<Letter>();
lst = (from l in l.tblLetter.ToList() 
       select new {l.Id, l.Title, UserName = l.tblUser.Name}
      ).ToList();
```

and:

```
List<Letter> lst = new List<Letter>
    (from l in l.tblLetter.ToList() 
     select new {l.Id, l.Title, UserName = l.tblUser.Name});
```

but get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type...

Comment: Post the full exception.

Comment: It is because you are returning an Anonymous Type. Hence, it cannot convert the returned type to Letter.

Comment: @AnaMah are you trying to use a list, because you would like a strong typed list object from the Linq query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SnowYetis comments, you are actually selecting an instance of a new, anonymous type in your code.  That's what the syntax `new { ... }` does.  Notice that there's no type name after the `new` directive.

If your `Letter` type has the properties `Id`, `Title`, `UserName` then all you need to do is change `new { ... }` to `new Letter { ... }`.

If not, then we probably need more information than you're giving us—for example, the definition of the `Letter` type.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues in your code:

- `l.tblLetter.ToList()` returns all records from your table. You typically don't call `ToList()` until the end of your query, to get just the data you need and no more.
- You want to do a join between the two tables to get the matching user name.
- If you want to return a collection of `Letter`, you can create instances of that in your `select` statement instead of creating an anonymous type.

Try this:

```
var lst = (from l in l.tblLetter
           join u in tblUser on l.UserId equals u.Id
           select new Letter
           {
               Id = l.Id,
               Title = l.Title,
               UserName = u.Name
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: i want not use var type. i have select data and List<Letter> would fill. (Letter in calss in C#)

Comment: Actually, `var` is not a type at all!  It is a shorthand for, in this case, `List<Letter>`.  You can type `List<Letter> lst = (from...` in full, but the generated code is the same.  If you do need to fill an existing list, omit the `.ToList()` and assign the result of the linq query to an `IEnumerable<Letter>`.  Then call `list.AddRange(myEnumerable)` as @GrantWinney suggests.